# Can't generate seed data for prisma db

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, orm, prisma

I'm trying to generate seed data using the file below. When it runs, it tells me the journalEntry item needs a user, but I can't tell why, the example in the [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/migrate/seed-database) doesn't specify a user when `upsert`ing.

```js
async function main() {
  const food = await prisma.food.upsert({
    where: {
      id: 1,
    },
    create: {
      name: 'Protein shake',
      meal: 'DINNER',
      journalEntry: {
        create: {
         user: { // this is the problem
            create: {id: 1} 
          }
        }
      },
      macros: {
        create: {
          calories: 120,
          protein: 24,
          carbs: 3, 
          fat: 0,
        }
      },
      journalEntryId: 1,
      nutrientProfileId: 1,
    },
  })
  console.log(food);
}
```

### Models

```js
model User {
  id                Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
  username          String          @unique
  targetMacros      NutrientProfile @relation(fields: [nutrientProfileId], references: [id])
  journalEntries    JournalEntry[]
  nutrientProfileId Int
}

model NutrientProfile {
  id       Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  calories Int    @default(0)
  protein  Int    @default(0)
  carbs    Int    @default(0)
  fat      Int    @default(0)
  User     User[]
  Food     Food[]
}

model JournalEntry {
  id           Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt    DateTime @default(now())
  journalItems Food[]
  notes        String?   @db.VarChar(255)
  user         User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId       Int
}

model Food {
  id                Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
  name              String
  macros            NutrientProfile @relation(fields: [nutrientProfileId], references: [id])
  createdAt         DateTime        @default(now())
  journalEntry      JournalEntry?   @relation(fields: [journalEntryId], references: [id])
  journalEntryId    Int?
  nutrientProfileId Int
  meal              Meal
}

enum Meal {
  BREAKFAST
  LUNCH
  DINNER
  SNACK
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe the author thoughts readers had finished reading previous dependent articles already.......

the relationship in primsa

- it is strong relationship between model(model fields without question mark), in terms of the user id cannot be empty.

```
model JournalEntry {
  user         User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  ...
}
```

- if you would like to make userId as optional, you can add a question mark.

```
model User {
  id                Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
  journalEntries?    JournalEntry[]
}

model JournalEntry {
  user?         User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId        Int
}
```

For your case, you can either update the prisma model as mentioned above to remove strong relationship between models to fix your error or write code to seed user first.